# How to change numeric values and only matches word as the key inside files?

Tags: python

I am new at python and trying to make a simple config editor app.

I have a `.txt` files which is inside of it contains a bunch of word `count` like:

```
...
...
max_count=1000
count=123
host_count=000
...
...
```

In my case, I want to change only the exact word matches with `count=` as the key to `count=0` and whatever number on that (after `=` sign), I want it to be replaced by a value that user has given from the input field while ignoring the other counts like `max_count=, host_count=, etc`. Is it possible to do that?

For instance:

> When user typed 0 on the input field, the result would be `count=0`
>
> When user typed 1 on the input field, the result would be `count=1`
>
> The other `xxx_count=` or `count_xxx=` will be ignored

I tried to do it like below but all counts are replaced instead of only the matches word `count=` it self.

```py
files = Finder(self.path, self.name).find()

    for file in files:
        with open(file) as target:
            content = target.read()

            if self.target in content:
                print(content)
                content = content.replace(self.target, self.value)

                with open(file, "w") as target:
                    target.write(content)
            else:
                print('{} not found in {}'.format(self.target, file))
```

please help.

**UPDATE**

here is my Finder class (it only used to find the files).

```py
import os


class Finder:
    result = []

    """
    Create new instance.
    :param {string} path: the directory of the target file.
    :param {string} name: the name of the file.
    """

    def __init__(self, path, name):
        self.path = path
        self.name = name

    # Find files in the given path.
    def find(self):
        directory_exists = os.path.isdir(self.path)

        if not directory_exists:
            return print('Tidak dapat menemukan file {} di folder: {}.'.format(self.name, self.path))

        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(self.path):
            for file in files:
                if self.name in file:
                    self.result.append(os.path.join(root, file))

        return self.result
```

and it is the full version of my `Modifier` class:

```py
from modules.Finder import Finder
from pprint import pprint


class Modifier(Finder):
    """
    Create new instance.

    :param target: target to be modified.
    :param value: value to be used on target.
    """

    def __init__(self, path, name, target, value):
        self.target = target
        self.value = value
        Finder.__init__(self, path, name)

    def modify(self):
        files = Finder(self.path, self.name).find()

        if not files:
            return files

        for file in files:
            with open(file) as target:
                content = target.read()

                if self.target in content:
                    print(content)
                    content = content.replace(self.target, self.value)

                    with open(file, "w") as target:
                        target.write(content)
                else:
                    print('{} not found in {}'.format(self.target, file))
```

**UPDATE 2**

Just to make sure everybody understand what I want to do.. This is my `App.py` file which controls the program.

```py
from pprint import pprint
from modules.Modifier import Modifier

SMSGW = Modifier('D:\\Smsgw', 'SMSGW.ini', 'count=', 'count=0')

settings = SMSGW.modify()
pprint(settings)
```

Comment: Hello! Is `Finder` a class defined by you? Or is part of a library?

Comment: It's my helper class, sir.

Comment: So would be useful to see it. I have a guess about what could be the problem, but cannot be sure because I do not know how the class works.

Comment: Okay, I will update my code, sir

Comment: just change this line `content = content.replace(self.target, self.value)` to [kaushal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55936800/7704512)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use regular expression `^count=\d+$` to replace the exact match `count=somenumber`

Considering:
`user_input` is the input entered by user and `content` is the data read from file

```
import re
re.sub(r'^count=\d+$', 'count={}'.format(user_input), content)
```

Comment: Where should I put it on my code sir? it didn't work as I wrote it like this `content = re.sub(r'^count=\d+$', value, content)` or should I do it like this: `content = content.replace(re.sub(r'^count=\d+$', value, content))`?

Comment: Yeah! you got it right, ```re.sub``` returns the modified content, keeping the original content variable intact. Using ```content = content.replace(re.sub(r'^count=\d+$', value, content))``` will do!

Comment: It didn't work either, the regex is working when I tested it on notepad++ but when I implement it on `re.sub` it does not change the `count=xxx` value :(

Comment: that's because you have opened the same file in nested with context for different mode.

Comment: I don't understand, what does it means, sir?

Comment: I implemented it like this [code attachment](https://pastebin.com/pLYmQhKQ), am I wrong??

Comment: I have made a few changes, Check out the updated [code](https://pastebin.com/VnzDWqVY).

Comment: Thanks sir, I'd just found a solution, I only need to put a `flags` after the content variable. like this: `new_content = re.sub(regex, value, content, flags=re.M)`

Answer (score 0):

I am not following exactly with you code, however the solution to your main question seems to be utilizing regex.

If your string is `s = 'x_count=1\ncount=0\ncount_xx=0'` or

```
x_count=1
count=0
count_xx=0
```

you can use regex to find and replace the number following `count=`

```
import re
s = 'x_count=1\ncount=0\ncount_xx=0'
## user inputs the number 1, so we replace the current number with 1
new_s = re.sub(r'\ncount=(\d)', r'\ncount=1', s)
```

let me know if this is helpful or not!

edit:

```
import re
user_input = 1
for file_name in list_of_file_names:
    with open(file_name) as f:
        new_file_content= re.sub(r'\ncount=(\d)', r'\ncount=%d'(user_input), f.read())

    with open(file_name, "w") as f:
        f.write(new_file_content)
```

Comment: Looks good sir, but what if I have 500++ files and which the number after `count=` is not the same as each other? I want to make it updated in one click using loops.

Comment: @DonnyPratama look at my edit. This takes a list of files, loops through them reading each and writing the new `count= ` value.

Comment: Thanks, I will try your answer once I have arrived to my office :)

Answer (score 0):

I see that in most cases you use the `in` statement to check strings. Like here:

```
if self.name in file:
```

or here

```
if self.target in content:
```

I think this is not what you need. The `in` statements checks if a string is contained in another strings, so for example `'a' in 'bac'` returns `True`. And also `count=` in `max_count=` returns `True`. So the problem may arise from here.

I guess you need to check for exact equality, so you should change these lines in:

```
if self.name == file:
```

or

```
if self.target == content:
```

Now to use this solution you need to separate the value from the target. Use the [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) method.

For example, if `content` is `"count=123"` you can do:

```
sepcontent = content.split('=')
```

this will create a list `sepcontent` which is `['count', '0']`. You can check for equality in the first element `if self.target == sepcontent[0]`.

And you definitely need to iterate line by line when doing this. So do not use `target.read()`, which will create a single string of the full file.

In the end you should have something like:

```
wfile = 'tempfile.txt'
with open(file) as target:
    with open(wfile, 'w') as wtarget:
        for content in target:
            sepcontent = content.split("=")
            if sepcontent[0] == "count": #or your self.target
                content = content.replace(spline[1], self.value)
            wtarget.write(content)
```

In the end you will have all your edits in a file called `tempfile.txt`. You may simply rename this file to substitute the original.